# How to use Makefile variables as files to include in g++ command?

Tags: c++, variables, makefile

Here's my problem : I have a makefile file containing the info to compile everything in my project to make my life easier, but it is giving me some headaches recently.

It can compile multiple files, such as this :

```
objects/io.o: sources/io.cpp
    @g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++11
objects/map.o: sources/map.cpp
    @g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++11
```

At the top of the makefile, I have variables declared as such :

```
IO="objects/io.o"
MAP="objects/map.o"
[... other object files ...]
ALL="$(IO) $(MAP) [...]"
```

When I want to compile my main file, I use this command :

```
main.exe: tests/main.cpp
    @g++ $< $(ALL) -o $@ -std=c++11
```

When I compile this problem manually (inputting everything in one line of command, instead of making `make main.exe`) it compiles without problems.

However, when I use the make command for the project, the following error pops up :

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'objects/io.o objects/map.o [...]'
make: *** [main.exe] Error 1
```

Can I not use variables this way ? I'm extremely confused. I know for a fact those files are compiled, it just seems the `make` utility doesn't understand file paths.

Comment: Remove all quotes.

Comment: I'm dumb. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have quoted your variables. Try unquoting them and they won't expand a single parameter:

```
ALL = $(obj1) $(obj2) ...
```

Also, for those objects which use the same compilation process I generally define a single rule:

```
obj/%.o: %.cc
    $(GCC) -o $@ -c $< $(FLAGS)
```

Obviously that would require defining the extra variables `GCC` and `FLAGS`

Comment: Quick question, does your overall command (the `obj/%.o: %.cc` ) recompiles every .o file everytime or does it only compiles the modified files ?

Comment: It only compiles object files when it's asked to. It will follow the same semantics as if you had manually specified each one. The way I typically use this is by requiring all the object files as a dependency of a library or the main executable. i.e. `main.exe: main.cc obj/obj1.o obj/obj2.o ...`. Of course that can be shortened by putting all your objects into a variable